Hola ¿Cómo se puede mostrar la hora actual del sistema?
Quiero mostrar la hora del sistema, mi duda es si se puede hacer con time o tiene que ser datetime:
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-12"hidden>
                <label for="" class="medium">fecha reporte</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="datetime" name="fechaReporte"  value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                <label for="" class="medium">Hora reporte</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" name="horaReporte" value="<?php echo date("G:i");?>">
            </div>


No es muy clara la pregunta. En el título dices "mostrar la hora" y en el contenido dice que quieres guardar la hora en la base de datos; y pones un HTML. Si quieres mostrar la hora en tiempo real, lo mejor es con Javascript. Para guardar en la BD: Con PHP: date('Y-m-d H:i:s') o desde la propia BD: NOW()

@aeportugal solo quiero ver la hora con php

ok y que has intentado lo que veo de php ... solo imprime, eso no mostrara nada en tiempo real???

no tiene sentido mostrar la hora del sistema basandote en php ... ten en cuenta que php se ejecuta en el backend y el html esta en el cliente.. asi como lo presentas, lo imprimira de forma estatica, y no cambiara en tiempo real, para que se muestre la hora en tiempo real tendrias que hacer request o consumir un websocket ... y para eso necesitarias implementar javascript/ajax etc ... y sigue no siendo correcto por que el reques tendra su delay .... dependiendo de la red podria el cliente ver un retraso ... en la hora ...

te recomendaria calcular la diferencia horaria entre el servidor y el cliente y a partir de hay, con javascript llevar la hora del sistema usando la local... pero todo eso tendrias que hacerlo s en javascript y no veo ningun intento relacionado ...

Por lo que dice tu , lo que presentas en la fecha de generación de un reporte. Generalmente eso responde a la pregunta de "¿cuándo se generó este reporte?". Si para ti es suficiente responder con la fecha, puedes enviar date('Y-m-d') a un campo de tipo DATE en la base de datos. Si quieres responder algo como "El 5 de abril a las 3:14 de la tarde", usa date('Y-m-d H:i:s') hacia un campo de tipo DATETIME o TIMESTAMP. Personalmente yo prefiero usar campos de tipo DATETIME pues te dan la flexibilidad de consultar no solamente por fecha sino también por hora en caso de que lo necesites.

@JuanCarlos Hola use date('G:i:s') para imprimir la hora y mostrarla, y a la hora de enviarla a la base de datos la rescato como TIME, hice pruebas de inyección y hasta ahora me lo recibe bien.

@DiegoSoto Aunque no mencionas qué motor de bases de datos estás utilizando, MySQL, Postgre, SQL Server y Oracle database (a riesgo de iniciar una guerra yo diría que son 4 de los más comunemente usados), manejan el formato TIME con horas de dos caracteres (HH), mientras que el formato 'G' de la función date() puede producir horas de un caracter ya que no inserta un cero a la izquierda de la hora. Lo menciono solamente para que puedas considerar si debes cambiar a date(H:i:s)

@JuanCarlos Hola el motor de base de datos que ocupo es MySQL y claro creo que la mejor manera es H:i:s. Gracias

La opción para mostrar la hora del sistema sería:


<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
    <label for="" class="medium">Hora reporte (Hora del informe):</label>
    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="horaReporte" value="<?php echo date("G:i"); ?>">
</div>



Si necesita capturar tanto la fecha como la hora para fines de informes, puede mantener el tipo de entrada datetime de otra manera se puede seguir usando time
